# Download text file with Node

Tags: node.js, http, fs

I want to download and save a text file using Node. But after downloading the `pipe` method return an error to memory lack. By setting `emitter` size to zero(0) the error is disappeared but the size of the file exceed to 1 GB!

```
var download = function (uri, filename, callback) {                    
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    http.get(uri, function (res) {
    res.pipe(file); 
        res.on('end', function () {
            file.end();                           
        });
    });
};
```

> ERROR: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
>   detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter

I couldn't find any solution to save a text file from web. What's the best way to do this?

**EDIT:**
I move pipe method to solve memory problem. But in the file it puts binary data not **text**. How can I save file as a text file?

Comment: You should call `pipe` just once, your problem is that you call it multiple times, upon every `data` event emitted. Your code incorrectly combines two approaches: a chunk-by-chunk write based on `data`/`end` events and `pipe`lining this that should be done in a single call.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Got it! But what about text file. pipe method create a file with binary body not a text! What should I do to save it as a text. My file is a json file

Comment: Isn't it now an encoding issue? Like they return utf-16 file or something? Try experimenting with creation options like `createWriteStream( filename, { encoding: 'utf-16' } )`. That's a pure guess, though.

Comment: "But in the file it puts binary data not text."  Why should it matter?  Byte-for-byte, you want to take whatever you get and write it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

A possible try could be:

> npm i request

then following code instead of yours:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var download = function (uri, filename, callback) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file));
};
```

This way it will handle memory/network/back-pressure on its own in nearly all cases.

Answer (score 0):

This code writes a UTF-8 string to the text file at `filepath`, but it appears to be functionally equivalent to your latest update (edit 3).

If you're still getting binary/buffered output after trying this code, please provide the result of `typeof res`.

```
const downloadFile = (uri, filepath, callback) => {
  http.get(uri, res => {
    console.log(typeof res);
    res.pipe(fs.createWriteFileStream(filepath))
      .on('finish', callback);
  });
};
```